# Matching multiple classes with dapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper

How can I retrieve this objects with Dapper?
For example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ClassB b { get; set; }
    public ClassC c  { get; set; }
    public ClassD d { get; set; }
    public ClassE e { get; set; }
    public ClassF f { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Text {get; set;}
}
    ...

public class ClassF
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

I use  `connection.Query<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD, ClassE, ClassF, ClassA>(sql, ... )` but Dapper only allows multi mapping with maximum 5 arguments.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered changing the code?

Comment: These are classes for example. In my project I use classes with more functionality. Not only text container.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I move the fields that I need to de main class.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string TextB { get; set; }

    public string TextC{ get; set; }

    public string TextD{ get; set; }
}



    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {
                    OpenConnection(sqlConnection);
                    string sql = @"select a.id 'Id', a.text 'Text', b.text 'TextB', c.text 'TextC', d.text 'TextD' 
                                    from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.idB = b.id inner join tableC c on a.idC = c.id 
                                         inner join tableD d on a.idD = d.id";
                    var rows = sqlConnection.Query<ClassA>(sql).ToList();
                    return rows.ToList();
                }
```